# What is lifecycle for RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle

I'm requesting images from presenter in adapter:

```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(SiteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
  {
    Site site = sites.get(position);
    holder.siteName.setText(site.getName());
    requestHolderLogo(holder, site.getLinks().getLogoUrl());
  }

  private void requestHolderLogo(final ViewHolder holder, final String logoUrl)
  {
    compositeSubscription.add(
      presenter.bitmap(logoUrl)
        .subscribe(
          bitmap -> {
            holder.siteLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            holder.siteLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          },
          error -> {
            holder.siteName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          })
    );
  }
```

I should unsubscribe when `ViewHolder` is re-used. It is easy.

But how stop all subscription when view is destroyed? I should also probably nullify presenter reference to avoid memory leak

Comment: Please explain why downvoting

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68351804/6039240

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think the best way to do that would be to:

1. Keep a `subscription` reference in the `SiteAdapter.ViewHolder`
2. `unsubscribe` the `subscription` object in `onBindViewHolder` (it's called when the `ViewHolder` is reused)
3. Keep the `CompositeSubscription` object in your `adapter`
4. Use the `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` method of your `Adapter` to `unsubscribe` the `compositeSubscription`

Like so:

```
public class SiteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SiteAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();

    // other needed SiteAdapter methods

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SiteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.subscription != null && !holder.subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            compositeSubscription.remove(holder.subscription);
            // this will unsubscribe the subscription as well
        }
        Site site = sites.get(position);
        holder.siteName.setText(site.getName());
        requestHolderLogo(holder, site.getLinks().getLogoUrl());
    }

    private void requestHolderLogo(final SiteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final String logoUrl) {
        holder.subscription = presenter.bitmap(logoUrl)
                .subscribe(
                        bitmap -> {
                            holder.siteLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            holder.siteLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        },
                        error -> {
                            holder.siteName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        });
        compositeSubscription.add(holder.subscription);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        compositeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public Subscription subscription;

        // some holder-related stuff

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // init holder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, so there is no method on adapter that is called when `RecyclerView` is detached from activity

Comment: Well... actually there is one - `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` and it could easily do what the `recycle()` currently does. Good idea :)

Comment: `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` is being called when you changing adapters, but it is not being called when configuration changed :/

Comment: @Miha_x64 that seems to be like a whole [another issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132643/recyclerview-doesnt-unregister-itself-from-the-adapter-on-orientation-change)

Comment: How will you solve the same problem if the subscription is something that keeps listening for more data? For context, i am using firebase data change listener.

Comment: @Adi and this kind of subscription is kept inside `ViewHolders`?

Comment: @BartekLipinski Yes because each listener has to update data from a different endpoint. In my case, the listener for a particular viewholder is listening for changes for a chat group id attached to that viewholder and updating the textview. If you have a better design in mind, i will love to know.

Comment: Where does `siteLogo` comes from? What is it's type?

Comment: @VictorQueiroz this is something that was copied from the question and is "hidden" behind the comment `// some holder-related stuff`

Answer (score 7):

For others which have the same problem:
viewDetachedFromWindow in the adapter is only called when the adapter is set to null in the onPause (Activity, Fragment) or onDetachFromWindow (Activity, Fragment)

recyclerview.setAdapter(null)

Then you get viewDetachedFromWindow(...) where you can release your internal states and subscriptions. I would setup your subscriptions in on bind, make sure before every bind call you relase old subscriptions as a view can be recycled.

Another possibility is to inflate a custom view instead of only a layout in your factory. Then you can make the cleanup in the custom view onDetachFromWindow(). You get the onDetachedFromWindow also without setting the adapter to null.

Comment: How will you solve the same problem if the subscription is something that keeps listening for more data? For context, i am using firebase data change listener.

Comment: @Adi I would make a custom view and use onDetachFromWindow()

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem i believe. onDetachFromWindow is called when the activity is active and a recycler view is scrolled out of window. But if you close an activity, then this method is not called for the views last visible on window. So there would be memory leak.

Comment: @Adi onDetachFromWindow is also called when the activity is destroyed for example when you press the android back button.

Comment: So much hours wasted on this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

One can call `public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull VH holder)`
[image]