# RecyclerView.Adapter onViewDetachedFromWindow never called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

What's the way to go if I want my ViewHolders in an RecyclerView to clean up internal state (in this case unregister from an EventBus and clean up Rx-Subscriptions)?
I thought that the methods `onViewDetachedFromWindow` or `onViewRecycled`in the adapter is the callback where I can cleanup resources (as described in the API), but this method is never called when I change from the `Activity` with the `RecyclerView` to another `Activity`.

Only `onViewAttachedToWindow` is called when the activity is entered and i can see my items.

My adapter looks like this:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> 
{
    @Override 
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return factory.getViewholder(parent, viewType, this);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItem item = items.get(position);
    holder.bind(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(MyViewHolder holder)
    {
        holder.viewDetached();
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(MyViewHolder holder)
    {  
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        holder.viewAttached();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(MyViewHolder holder)
    {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        holder.viewRecycled();
    }

    @Override 
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return items.get(position).getType(this.factory);
    }
}
```

The `Activity` holding the `RecyclerView`:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

   protected void setupView()
   {
        //called in onCreate

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        this.adapter = new Adapter(new ItemViewHolderFactory());
   }

    @Override
    public void setItems(List<MyItem> items)
    {
        //items are loaded async
        this.adapter.setItems(items);
        this.recyclerView.setAdapter(this.adapter);
        this.recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    }
}
```

The ViewHolder looks like this

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
        public void bind(MyItem item)
        {
          //set initial data
        }

       public void viewAttached()
       {
        registerToEventBus();
        loadDataAsync(); // here an rx operation is scheduled and a subscription is hold
       }

     public void viewDetached()
     {
         unregisterFromEventBus();
         cancelAsyncOperationAndCleanSubscription();
     }
}
```

Thanks for any advices.

**EDIT**
I tried to override `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` in the adapter, but this method is also not called.

Comment: Doesn't this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37675317/1889768) answer yours?

Comment: Not really, because in my case i have no knowledge about the implementation details  of the view holders. The code snippets are not complete, the adapter is a generic adapter and there can be different viewholders plugged in, each viewholder can either use an EventBus or Rx or whatever else. All i want to do is to inform the viewholders to cleanup.

Comment: Provide a base class for your `ViewHolder` with an abstract method `destroy()` and extend all your different `ViewHolder`s from that base class.

Comment: @Abbas i am already doing this, but when to call `destroy`?? I also tried to hook into `onDetachedFromRecyclerView`, but his method is also not called.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting adapter in your `RecyclerView` to null by calling mRecyclerView.setAdapter(null)? That should give you `onDetachedFromRecyclerView()` callback

Comment: @Abbas that was the missing part, thank you. I am now calling `recyclerView.setAdapter(null)` in `onPause` of my activity. It has now only the poor sideeffect, that (i tested that on emulator) the items disappear immediately before the next activity is started, so i see an "empty screen" for a short time.

Comment: An alternative is to call `setLayoutManager(null)`; not sure about the side-effect in your case; my RecyclerView is in a TabHost and it works fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I run into the same problem:

As already mentioned you can set the adapter null in the onPause (Activity, Fragment) or  onDetachFromWindow (Activity, Fragment)

```
recyclerview.setAdapter(null)
```

Then you get viewDetachedFromWindow(...) where you can release your internal states and subscriptions.
I would setup your subscriptions in on bind, make sure before every bind call you relase old subscriptions as a view can be recycled.

Another possibility is to inflate a custom view instead of only a layout in your factory. Then you can make the cleanup in the custom view onDetachFromWindow(). You get the onDetachedFromWindow also without setting the adapter to null.

Comment: With today's knowledge I would also prefer the solution with the custom views.