# RxJava unsubscribing in RecyclerView adapter presenter

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp, rx-java2

I've got a presenter that is created for the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. The presenter has a method to call into the API layer, then change some local data values. This is implemented as an Rx chain:

```
public void doStuff(Object args) {
    mRemote.doStuff(args)
            .doOnNext(count -> mLocal.setStuffCount(count))
            .firstOrError()
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribe(...)
    <...>
```

This method might be called several times with different arguments, and therefore generate different subscriptions. As I understand, RxJava will unsubscribe `onComplete` or `onError`. However, it is possible that there are, for example, 5 subscriptions created, and before they are resolved, the user moves on from the fragment, and therefore the `Adapter` is no longer relevant and should be collected. However, as I understand, it won't be collected cause of the active subscriptions, until those are resolved.

Normally I link the presenter with the related view, then store all subscriptions in a `CompositeDisposable` and clear the disposable when the lifecycle suggests it's time to clear (for example, a view goes to the `onPause` state). I could implement a similar approach here, however that means I would have to:

1) Establish a relationship between a view and the adapter, so that when the view's lifecycle method is triggered, it will take the adapter and invoke an unsubscribe method on it, which will then take the presenter and invoke `clear()`. Could I rely on `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` for that? Or would I have to do that manually?

2) Each time my presenter method to do stuff is called, I'll be creating a new subscription, which means the `CompositeDisposable` will grow in size until who know's what. Although the call has been executed, the disposable is still referenced in the `CompositeDisposable`.

I have a feeling there's a simpler solution here so hoping someone might point me at it.

EDIT:

Another solution that comes to mind, would be to create a presenter for each `ViewHolder` and link subscription to the binding and recycling of the holder. However, that means keeping a few more presenters hanging around - but the approach seems a bit cleaner.

Comment: So the Observable stuff are in your presenter? Don't you have at least basic lifecycle events at the presenter?

Comment: Yes, Rx chain and `CompositeDisposable` is in my presenter. Yes,  `Presenter` is lifecycle-agnostic on purpose. I mean I can add methods to it that I'll call on lifecycle events, however which lifecycle events to use in an `Adapter`? Anyway, have a look at my own answer, might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to be useful to anyone but this is how I've solved this problem.

I ended up merging my `Presenters` while keeping different `View` interfaces for the `ViewHolder` and the `Fragment` (will call them `ViewHolderView` and `FragmentView`).

I liked the idea of having a `Presenter` for each `ViewHolderView`, however, it didn't really solve my problem. I was keeping my `CompositeDisposable` inside the `Presenter`, but with that approach, I had to move it out to the `Adapter` level and keep a reference to the `Disposable` inside my `ViewHolder`. Similar to the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674692/what-is-lifecycle-for-recyclerview-adapter)

I didn't like the idea of manipulating the `Adapter` from the `Fragment` lifecycle manually as I was already calling `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()` on `FragmentView`, and `onDetachedFromRecyclerView` is not called unless you nullify the adapter on the `RecyclerView`

The solution was to merge my `Adapter` presenter with my `Fragment` presenter while keeping the `ViewHolderView` interface. So I ended up with a contract for one `Presenter`, and two separate `View` interfaces, and I'm passing the `Presenter` to the `Adapter`. When `FragmentView` unsubscribes, it cleans up everything.