# How to unregister LocalBroadcastManager in ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, memory-leaks, android-viewholder, localbroadcastmanager

I have a `ViewHolder` that registers as a receiver for the `LocalBroadcastManager`.
The `ViewHolder` also has a delegate to the `Activity` that holds the `RecyclerView`.

This causes a memory leak, because I can't manage to unregister the broadcast manager in the view holder when the activity is destroyed.

```
public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public interface Delegate {
        ...
    }

    private @Nullable Delegate delegate;

    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void bind(@NonNull Delegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        registerNotifications();
    }

    public void recycle() {
        unregisterNotifications();
        delegate = null;
    }

    private void registerNotifications() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyFilter));
    }

    private void unregisterNotifications() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

I tried to call `recycle` in the `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s `onViewDetachedFromWindow` and `onViewRecycled`. But it seems that there is no guarantee that any of these will be called when the activity is destroyed.

How can I make sure that the broadcast receiver is unregistered properly when the activity is destroyed or the ViewHolder is recycled?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674692/what-is-lifecycle-for-recyclerview-adapter/37675317#37675317. I'll try this solution and close this question if it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is lifecycle for RecyclerView adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674692/what-is-lifecycle-for-recyclerview-adapter)

Comment: I am not sure whether to delete or close the question as duplicate. I voted as duplicate, because the question may be a valuable, additional sign post for others.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The first post talks about RxJava subscription management. Your post is asking about managing LocalBroadcastManager in ViewHolders.